# is uiscrollview suiting my needs?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I got my app running to a point where I could fill my horizontal uiscrollview with content of images and text. However I am unsure if the concept of uiscrollview is really what fits my requirements, since the contentSize of the different views will not be the same regarding their heights. here is an illustration:

[image]

Lets say I want horizontal scrolling (blue) between 4 different views, each of those views contains of an image subview (same sizes) and a text subview. 
The text subview however will always take a different amount of space and thus height. How can I ensure to still have the ability of vertical scrolling (red) according to the actual height of a certain view and how do I define the height of the overall contentSize? 
If this is not possible in a uiscrollview, how else would you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to need to make each vertical view in it's own scrollview, and add each of those scrollviews as a subview of the horizontal scrollview.  Just make sure that the vertical scrollview's contentWidth is equal to it's frame width and the contentheight of the horizontal scrollview equal to it's frame height, otherwise you will intercept pan gestures and your UI will be irritating (had that problem in my own code in the past).

So your view hierarchy (from application window out) will be like:

Window->Viewcontroller.view->horizontal Scrollview->multiple vertical scrollviews->image/text/anything else

Comment: thanks, and how would i define the contentsize of the horizontal Scrollview?

Comment: horizontalScrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake((numberOfVerticalTiles)*horizontalScrollview.frame.size.width,horizontalScrollview.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this and @Putz1103 's solution is a fine way to do it.

- You could also use a `UIPageViewController` where each of your vertical views is an instance of a `UIViewController` subclass.
- A third option would be to use a `UICollectionView` for your horizontally scrolling view where each vertically scrolling view would be a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. This option takes memory management out of your hands as iOS will handle the dequeuing of reusable cells.

Depending on how many vertical views you have, you could find yourself with hundreds of views in the view hierarchy at the same time. With this in mind, `UICollectionView` might be the right answer.